# Rails slow load time for model with lots of has_many relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a project with a model (User) that has accumulated about a dozen 'has_many' relationships. While the User model itself doesn't hold a whole lot of data, it's extremely slow to load.

As a test, I discovered that it loads considerably faster if I comment out the 'has_many' relationships.

Obviously I can't do this in practice, but what's happening with 'has_many' that causes it's significantly increase the load time? I can't imagine it's actually querying for these relations, right?

What can I do to speed this up?

Comment: One fact that may be useful- the User model is a shared inheritance table. It's actually the Customer model- which derives from the User model- that has this difficulty. Not sure if that make a difference here.

Comment: are you using STI. If you are check if you have an index on the type column  Having defined associations in the model as has_many has nothing to do with the query unless you are querieng all of them through eager loading or some type of join explicitly.

Comment: Have you considere create an index on each column of every table???

Answer (score 0):

Just do not call association without necessary and check if any preloadings are enabled.